# "ReferenceError: L is not defined" with leaflet clustering plugins

Tags: javascript, leaflet, requirejs

I've made the map that contains multiple markers and some of them have identical coordinates so I can see only one of them.
I've been looking for a solution to this problem and find a few clustering plugins for leaflet (like leaflet.markercluster or PruneCluster) and I've tried to use some of them, but every time I got an error "ReferenceError: L is not defined"  within plugin code.

First of all I'm including libraries and files:

```
$('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/upl/' + w_code + '/widget/style.css" >');
$('head').append('<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/upl/' + w_code + '/widget/libraries/leaflet.css" >');
$('head').append('<script data-main="scripts/main" src="/upl/' + w_code + '/widget/libraries/require.js"></script>');
requirejs(["/upl/" + w_code + "/widget/libraries/leaflet.js"], function (leaflet) {});
requirejs(["/upl/" + w_code + "/widget/libraries/PruneCluster.js"], function (PruneCluster) {});
```

Later in code, I'm trying to initialize map and add the markers (mapMarkers object):

```
map = L.map('popup-map').setView([55.7504461, 37.6174943], 11);

var pruneCluster = new PruneClusterForLeaflet();

mapMarkers.forEach(function (element) {
  var marker = new PruneCluster.Marker(element.coords);
  pruneCluster.RegisterMarker(marker);
});

map.addLayer(pruneCluster);
```

Comment: Are you declaring `L` somewhere else in your code? In your code you show you're calling `.map` on `L`, but it's not declared, so the error is correct `L` is not defined.

Comment: Have you tried googling that error message? I did a moment ago and found more than a handful (for example, [this one](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6238)) but not knowing more about your app I can't say exactly which post would point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not declaring L anywhere. L.map is a leaflet function to initialize the map, and it's working, I'm not getting the error on this line. The error "L is not defined" in console refers to the line in "PruneCluster.js" file.

Comment: And of course, I've tried to googling information about that error message. But there's a difference between situations: in most of the topics that I found on google or on StackOverflow, people have problems with referring to L from their own code, and in my code it works (for example L.map works fine), error appears only when there's a calling to L from clustering plugin code.
Regardless, I've also tried some of the solutions that I found on google (for example, I've already tried to include an older version of leaflet or import it with cdn instead of including it locally via requirejs).

Comment: @yurwd You work this one out?